# Mysql Irregular Auto_Increment increment

Tags: mysql, sql, auto-increment

The table is as follows. Interestingly, the 'id' column with Auto_Increment is increasing irregularly and high.

```sql
SELECT * FROM `numbers_api` ORDER BY `id` DESC

 id         |  email                |  name
--------------------------------------------
  562984864 | bla[at]blabla.com     |  test
  562956541 | bla1[at]blabla.com    |  test1
  562944637 | bla2[at]blabla.com    |  test2
  562944634 | bla3[at]blabla.com    |  test3
```

**Table structure for id:**

[image]

I am doing the insert operation into this table as follows ($Querys[] inside a loop) :

```php
$Querys[] = "INSERT IGNORE INTO numbers_api (email, name) VALUES ('" . $customerEmail . "', '" . $name . "');";

$this->db->query(implode("\r\n", $Querys));
```

Comment: can you share the schema please?

Comment: The contract for an auto increment column only says that the values generated will be unique, and generally increasing, nothing else.  If you need a sequence, then use your data to generate it when you query.

Comment: Run `SHOW CREATE TABLE numbers_api` and post the result [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70706541/edit)

Comment: I added the table structure for the id column

Comment: *column with Auto_Increment is increasing irregularly and high* Autoincrement guarantees that the next generated value will be greater than previous one. That's all! It does not guarantee the adjacency.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen *The contract for an auto increment column only says that the values generated will be **unique*** - NO. In MySQL at least. After the generation the uniqueness is checked by the primary key constraint. Exclusion - MyISAM and secondary autoincremented column in the PK, it has its own AI generating procedure which uses MAX+1 algorithm.

Comment: *Table structure for* Always provide the structure as complete and unchanged output for SHOW CREATE TABLE statement. In all another cases you may skip details (including ones which are hiddenly added as your current defaults) which are critical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a unique index on `email`, `name` or their combination.

Everytime you try to insert a row, an ID gets created. But only when `INSERT IGNORE` succeeds, i.e. when no unique constraint gets violated, will this ID be used.

With

```
create table numbers_api (id int auto_increment, email varchar(100), name varchar(100));

create unique index idx on table numbers_api (email, name);

INSERT IGNORE INTO numbers_api (email, name) VALUES ('A', 'A');

INSERT IGNORE INTO numbers_api (email, name) VALUES ('A', 'A');
INSERT IGNORE INTO numbers_api (email, name) VALUES ('B', 'B');

INSERT IGNORE INTO numbers_api (email, name) VALUES ('A', 'A');
INSERT IGNORE INTO numbers_api (email, name) VALUES ('B', 'B');
INSERT IGNORE INTO numbers_api (email, name) VALUES ('C', 'C');
```

The table will have three rows:

| id | email | name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | A |
| 3 | B | B |
| 6 | C | C |

because the second insert on A|A fails, thus wasting the ID 2, and the attempts to insert A|A and B|B after inserting the first B|B also fail, wasting IDs 4 and 5.

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca09b5c09ed10116bf27d83935f3e608

Comment: Thank you for keeping me informed with your deep knowledge. Also, if you like the way I ask questions, please rate them because I don't have the right to ask questions again yet.